# overloading std::exception - what() cannot convert const char*

Tags: c++, exception, overloading

I am writing my exception class:

```
class MyExcept: public std::exception
{
public:
    MyExcept(std::string _msg);
    virtual ~MyExcept() throw();
    virtual const char* what() const throw();

private:
    std::string m_errorMsg;
};


MyExcept::MyExcept(std::string _msg)
: m_errorMsg(_msg)
{
}

MyExcept::~MyExcept() throw()
{
}

const char* MyExcept:: what() const throw()
{
    return m_errorMsg.c_str;
}
```

I compiling with g++ and get the following error for the return line in the function what():

> cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::c_str, std::allocator >’ from type ‘const char* (std::__cxx11::basic_string::)() const’ to type ‘const char*’
>     return m_errorMsg.c_str;

What I am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: `c_str` is a function. You should call it, not return it. `return m_errorMsg.c_str;` => `return m_errorMsg.c_str();`

Comment: Using `throw()` is not recommended, it is *deprecated* in `C++11`. **see:** http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec

Comment: I am currntly not writing in c++11. STD::exception is using throw(). Am I allowed to inherit and not use it? Thanks

Comment: Your exception class is pretty much duplicating what `std::runtime_error` does. Maybe you should inherit from that instead so that you don't need to re-implement the exception message.

Comment: The error message shows that you are writing in C++11 (or later)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `return m_errorMsg.c_str();`, and it should work - `c_str` is a *function*, not a *variable*.